# Codeigniter routes not working aside from welcome controller in Linux (Elementary OS)

Tags: php, routes, codeigniter-3

I've been working in a codeigniter application that was copied from windows to linux. It is 100% working in windows platform but when i tried to run it in my linux machine (Running on Elementary OS) it started to give me an error 404 for every controller aside from the default controller (Welcome) Controller. I edited my .htaccess to look like this one but it doesn't seem to work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I already tried searching in the internet and try playing with my htaccess to work but same things happened.

This is my controller and routes

Home Controller.php

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class home extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('main_page');
    }
}
```

as you see the controller only display a certain HTML file.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Thanks, I've been stuck in this on this problem for almost 3 days. :( Hope that someone will help me out there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the name of my controller to Uppercase the first letter works like a charm!  I didn't notice that it was in the documentation.